# R programming Function (Returning a subset of Real Mean Squared)

Tags: r, vector, statistics, numeric, rms

I am new to R and am working on writing some cool functions while I learn statistics in parallel.  I'm trying to make a function that will take a numeric vector, perform the "root mean squared" operations and then have the output return essentially same vector with the possible outliers removed.

For example, if the vector is c(2,4,9,10,100) the resulting RMS would be about 37.

Therefore, I want the output to return the same vector with the possible outlier (in this case, 100) removed from the dataset.  So the result would be 2, 4, 9, 10

I put my code below but the output isn't working.  I tried it 2 different ways.  Everything up to the line that says RMS final works.  But below that it does not.

How can I modify this function so that it does what I want?  Also, as a bonus, and this might be asking a lot but based on my coding below, any tips for a newbie on making functions would be something I'd be grateful for as well. Thanks so much!

```
RMS_x <- c(2,4,9,10,100)

#Root Mean Squared Function - Takes a numeric vector
RMS <- function(RMS_x){
    RMS_MEAN <- mean(RMS_x)
    RMS_DIFF <- (RMS_x-RMS_MEAN)
    RMS_DIFF_SQ <- RMS_DIFF^2
    RMS_FINAL <- sqrt(sum(RMS_DIFF_SQ)/length(RMS_x))

    for(i in length(RMS_x)){
            if(abs(RMS_x[i]) > RMS_FINAL){
                  output <- RMS_x[i]}
                  else {NULL} }
    return(output)  
}




#Root Mean Squared Function - Takes a numeric vector
RMS <- function(RMS_x){
  RMS_MEAN <- mean(RMS_x)
  RMS_DIFF <- (RMS_x-RMS_MEAN)
  RMS_DIFF_SQ <- RMS_DIFF^2
  RMS_FINAL <- sqrt(sum(RMS_DIFF_SQ)/length(RMS_x))

    #output <- ifelse(abs(RMS_x) > RMS_FINAL,RMS_x, NULL)
  return(RMS_FINAL)  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following in the first lines of the RMS function.

```
RMS <- function(RMS_x) {
   bp <- boxplot(RMS, plot = FALSE)
   RMS_x <- RMS_x[!(RMS_x %in% bp$out)]
   ...
```

Now, you have `RMS_x` sans the outliers.

The boxplot function has a way of determining the outliers. Here, I am using that to remove them.

Comment: I wanted to fix it as an exercise to learn R and not really to accomplish anything in particular.  And so I don't really want to use a boxplot.  I just want to learn how to make it work the way I had envisioned.  But I do thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking more specifically about R and R functions I’ll focus my response on that. There are a couple errors I'll point out then provide a few alternative solutions.

Your first function isn’t producing the output you want for two reasons:

1. The logic instructs the function to return a single value rather than a vector. If you’re trying to load a vector within your for loop (one without the outlier) make sure to initialize the vector outside of the function : `output <- vector()` (note that in my solution below however this is not required). Also the value it is returning is just a value in your vector RMS_x  that is greater than the RMS rather that finding an outlier, just fyi if that's what you wanted.
2. There’s an error and/or typo in your for loop argument, it’s minor but it turns your for loop into not-a-loop whatsoever – which is obviously the total opposite of what you intended. The for loop needs a vector to loop through, the argument should be: `for(i in 1:length(RMS_x))`

In your code the loop is jumping straight to i = 5 because that is the length of your vector (`length(RMS_x) = 5`). Given that the values in the RMS_x vector were already in ascending order your code happens to give the "right" answer but that's just because of how you initially loaded the vector. This may have been a typo in your question, and it's a difference of only 2 code characters, but it totally changes what the function looks for.

## Solution:

To get what you are trying to accomplish, you need to write two functions: 1.)  that defines what's considered an outlier in your data set and 2.) a second function that strips out the outliers and calculates RMS. Then from there either make the functions independent or nest them to pass variables (this kind of goes with your bonus request as well since it's multiple ways of writing functions).

#### Function to identify outliers:

```
outlrs <- function(vec){

 Q1 <- summary(vec)["1st Qu."]
 Q3 <- summary(vec)["3rd Qu."]

 # defining outliers can get complicated depending on your sample data but 
 # your data set is super simple so we'll keep it that way
 IQR <- Q3 - Q1
 lower_bound <- Q1 - 1.5*(IQR)
 upper_bound <- Q3 + 1.5*(IQR)

 bounds <- c(lower_bound, upper_bound)
 return(bounds)
 assign("non_outlier_range", bounds, envir = globalEnv())

 # the assign() function will create an actual object in your  environment 
 # called non_outlier_range that you can access directly - return() 
 # just mean the result will be spit out into the console or into a variable
 # you load it into

}
```

#### Now moving on to the second function, a few options here:

First Way:  Input bounds argument into RMS_func()

```
RMS_func <- function(dat, bounds){

 dat <- dat[!(dat < min(bounds)) & !(dat > max(bounds))] 

 dat_MEAN <- mean(dat)
 dat_DIFF <- (dat-dat_MEAN)
 dat_DIFF_SQ <- dat_DIFF^2
 dat_FINAL <- sqrt(sum(dat_DIFF_SQ)/length(dat))

 return(dat_FINAL)  

}

# Call function from approach 1 - note that here the assign() in the 
# definition of outlrs() would be required to refer to non_outlier_range:

RMS_func(dat = RMS_x, bounds = non_outlier_range)
```

Second Way: Call outlrs() inside the second function

```
 RMS_func <- function(dat){

 bounds <- outlrs(vec = dat)

 dat <- dat[!(dat < min(bounds)) & !(dat > max(bounds))] 

 dat_MEAN <- mean(dat)
 dat_DIFF <- (dat-dat_MEAN)
 dat_DIFF_SQ <- dat_DIFF^2
 dat_FINAL <- sqrt(sum(dat_DIFF_SQ)/length(dat))

 return(dat_FINAL)  

}

# Call RMS_func - here the assign() in outlrs() would not be needed is not 
# needed because the output will exist within the functions temp environment
# and be passed to RMS_func
RMS_func(dat = RMS_x)
```

Third Way: Nest outlrs() definition within the RMS_Func - in this case you only need one nested function to accomplish your task

```
 RMS_Func <- function(dat){

    outlrs <- function(vec){

    Q1 <- summary(dat)["1st Qu."]
    Q3 <- summary(dat)["3rd Qu."]
    #Q1 <- quantile(vec)["25%"]
    #Q3 <- summary(vec)["75%"]

    IQR <- Q3 - Q1
    lower_bound <- Q1 - 1.5*(IQR)
    upper_bound <- Q3 + 1.5*(IQR)

    bounds <- c(lower_bound, upper_bound)
    return(bounds)

  }

bounds <- outlrs(vec = dat)

dat <- dat[!(dat < min(bounds)) & !(dat > max(bounds))] 

dat_MEAN <- mean(dat)
dat_DIFF <- (dat-dat_MEAN)
dat_DIFF_SQ <- dat_DIFF^2
dat_FINAL <- sqrt(sum(dat_DIFF_SQ)/length(dat))


return(dat_FINAL)  

}
```

P.S. Wrote this pretty quickly - will likely re-test and edit later. Hopefully for now this helps.